# Is it possible to generate JS from TypeScript surrounded by require() instead of define()?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I already understood how to load modules (tip: you should always start with ./ when referencing files relatively, even on the same folder), and created an application that is totally written using TypeScript.

The current issue I'm facing is: how to USE modules I wrote? Right now I'm employing a main.js file similar to:

```
require(['my/typescript/module'], function(module) {
    //my application boostrapping code goes here
 });
```

But by doing it this way I lose various advantages from TypeScript:

1. I'm unable to use ES6-style imports (c'mon, `import {Module} from
   './my/typescript/module'` looks way cleaner to me)
2. I can't get the type system from TypeScript, as I'm writing JavaScript directly
3. The project build don't break if I add some wrong import reference
4. (The worse part IMO) I can't get the autocomplete feature from the modules (again, I'm inside a JavaScript file)

So, I wonder if there are any possibility to combine ES6 imports and TypeScript, generating a require()-enclosed JS file instead of a define() one.

Answer (score 0):

To use ES6-style import, I think you should export the module first

```js
export default class SomeRamdomClass {    
    hello(name: string) {
        return `hello ${name}`;
    }
}

import importedRamdomClass from "./SomeRamdomClass";

let greeting = new importedRamdomClass();
console.log(greeting.hello('Jon'));
```

more information can be found on [TypeScriptLang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Comment: Fabio, thanks for your answer. I already have successfully exported my classes, all of them are accessible, I'm inheriting them, referencing them and so on. What I'm trying here is to require what I already defined using TypeScript only.